# Suppose $X,Y,Z$ are random variables such that $Y,X$ are perfectly correlated. Does it hold that $P(Z|X,Y) = P(Z|Y)$?

Tags: probability, correlation, independence, measure-theory, conditioning

Suppose $X,Y,Z$ are random variables such that $Y,X$ are perfectly correlated. I am wondering if it holds that $P(Z|X,Y) = P(Z|Y)$? It would seem that $X$ would then be a substitute of $Y$. Is there a way to formally prove this?

Comment: So the above only holds true if there exists a linear relationship between $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: Formally, P(X=x)=0 for typical continuous distributions. So yes: 0=0. Once you formalize this for some notion of set correlation, you can probably argue with nonzero  P(X≤x)=P(X≤x,Y≤y)=P(Y≤y) for y=f(x) if f is monotone increasing (similar, for monotone decreasing). I don't see why it should be restricted to linear relationships.

Comment: Just to get behind your definitions, do you consider the following variables X and Y, with correlation coefficient 1, still 'perfectly' correlated? $$Y \sim Unif(0,1)$$ and $$X = \begin{cases} Y& \quad if Y<1 \\ -Y& \quad if Y =1\end{cases}$$

Comment: Suppose X,Y are random dice rolls such that Y=X are somehow perfectly correlated, and Z is the sum of X and Y.  How should we interpret P(Z=z|Y=y)? Does it include the knowledge about the correlation? Is it an experimentally determined probability (counting the cases)? Is it a theoretical probability such as we calculate for fair dice?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In short the answer is that **yes** this is true, but proving it requires some manipulation of the measure theoretic definitions of probability: largely because the definition of conditional independence is heavily steeped in measure theory.

Note that perfect correlation implies that almost surely $X = aY + b$ for some constants $a,b$.

Now we turn to the measure theory, recall that by Bayes formula

$$\mathbf P[ Z = z \, | X = ay + b , \, Y =y ] = \frac{ \mathbf P[Z = z, \, X = ay + b,\, Y = y ] }{\mathbf P[ X = ay + b,\, Y = y ]}.$$

Moreover, measure theoretically if the random variables $X,Y,Z \colon \Omega \rightarrow \mathbf R$ then the event $\{X = x\}$ etc. are defined as

$$ \{X = x\} = \{ \omega \in \Omega \, \colon \, X(\omega) = x\},$$

further since $X$ is almost surely equal to $aY + b$ we have that up to a sets of measure $0$

$$\{X = ay + b\} = \{Y = y\},$$

and hence their intersection is, up to sets of measure $0$
$$\{X = ay + b\} \cap \{Y = y\} = \{Y = y\}.$$

This can now be substituted into Bayes formula to derive the desired result

\begin{align*}\mathbf P[ Z = z \, | X = ay + b , \, Y =y ] &= \frac{ \mathbf P[Z = z, \, X = ay + b,\, Y = y ] }{\mathbf P[ X = ay + b,\, Y = y ]}\\
&=\frac{ \mathbf P[Z = z, \,  Y = y ] }{\mathbf P[ Y = y ]}\\
&=\mathbf P[ Z = z \, | \, Y =y ] .\end{align*}

Note that there is some level of detail omitted from this (largely around the sets of measure $0$ argument), but the essence is there.

Comment: (+1) Could we perhaps write directly
$X = g(Y) \implies \sigma (X, Y) = \sigma(g(Y), Y) = \sigma(Y)$ ?

Comment: So two things: in the above I tried to avoid too much measure theory detail as it wasn't clear to me whether the poster was interested in a solution using measure theory, though to answer the question I think you have to take this into account. Secondly, in regards to your suggestion: I think this is intuitively how I thought of it, that the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $X$ is identical to the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $Y$, and the result follows in some way.

Comment: The only point I'd make in your notation is that I'm not sure your statement is true for general $X = g(Y)$. For instance if $g \equiv 1$, then surely $\sigma(g(Y)) \neq \sigma(Y)$?

Comment: I didn't write $\sigma(g(Y))= \sigma(Y)$, I wrote $\sigma(g(Y), Y) = \sigma(Y)$

Comment: I would appreciate seeing the "omitted detail" because everything in this analysis assumes the denominators are nonzero.

Comment: I believe that this trickery with Bayes formula only works if you consider factual realizations of X, Y and Z. The P(Z=z|Y=y) may be different from P(Z=z|Y=y,X=ay+b) when you consider to include vacuous truths.

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos, apologies, I misread what you had put. Still one query though, it is not neccessarily the case that $X = g(Y)$ for some $g$ as would this not suggest the case that $X = aY + b$, and not that this need hold only almost surely?

Comment: @whuber, I'm not sure that I'm all that worried about the denominator being $0$; assuming the distributions are continuous then all expressions above should be replaced by their equivalents eg. $P(X = x) = P(X \in dx) = p_X(x)$.

Comment: But if that's the case then your conclusions are wrong!  I think perhaps you are assuming the joint density function itself is continuous--which is a stronger assumption.

Comment: Happy to be wrong if I am: I agree that the proof is only a sketch, and when it comes to measure theory there are plenty of places for intuition to fall down! However, can you expand on your point; why does this requie that the densities are continuous?